# the largest n that you can use in recursion factorial in R

Tags: r, recursion, factorial

I have a recursion factorial

```
recursive.factorial <- function(x) {
    if (x == 0)    return (1)
    else           return (x * recursive.factorial(x-1))
}
```

Just curious what can be the largest x here in my recursive.factorial v.s the build-int factorial() function in R? is there a way to check with that

Comment: And what happened when you *tried* various values of `x`? :-)

Comment: @paxdiablo then it returns Inf or even the error code evaluation nested too deeply: infinite recursion / options(expressions=)?

Comment: @paxdiablo it cannot exceed 170.

Comment: So, isn't *that* your answer? Or am I missing something?

Comment: @paxdiablo just want to know why is cannot exceed 170. I guess it's about the memory of the computer right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bit-span of computer numeric values seems much more likely to be the problem than the "computer memory" by which I am assuming you meant the address space of RAM. The largest value for an integer that can be represented without approximation in R (and any software package using the usual IEEE standard) is 2^53 - 1. There are other packages (some of them available as R packages)  that can support arbitrary precision numerics. The `?Recall` functions is a more stable methods of doing recursion, although it is not optimized in R. The `integer.max` is set at the precison obtainable with 2 bytes:

```
 2^32-1
[1] 4294967295
```

And the more recently introduced "long integers" max out at the limits of the mantissa of floating point "doubles".

```
> 2^53-1
[1] 9.007199e+15
> print( 2^53-1, digits=18)
[1] 9007199254740991
```

So as soon as you get a value of `factorial(n)` that is larger than that limit you only get an approximation and when you exceed the limits of the exponentiation for a "double" numeric, you get "Inf". My version of `factorial`  seems to have the same breaking point as yours:

```
> fact <- function(n)
+    if(n==0) { 1} else{ (n) *Recall(n-1)}
> fact (170)
[1] 7.257416e+306
> fact (171)
[1] Inf
```

Here's another way of thinking about calculating factorial:

```
> exp( sum(log(1:15)))
[1] 1.307674e+12
> factorial(15)
[1] 1.307674e+12
```

The "Stirling's approximation" is often used to speed up calculations of factorial. For more accurate values you can install either the `gmp` or the `Rmpfr` packages.